# Problems Implementing a Component from an Angular Library

Tags: html, angular, typescript, module, angular-library

So im making my own angular library.

I followed the steps listed here: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

So i created the library and published it to npmjs.com.

My issue is, whenever I tried making a new component inside the library,
It seems like the intellisense recognizes that the component is there however when i try to run my angular application i get faced with this error:

`ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.`

Here is a snippet of the librarys module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SlEcommComponent } from './sl-ecomm.component';
import { SlCatalogComponent } from './sl-catalog/sl-catalog.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [SlEcommComponent, SlCatalogComponent],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [SlEcommComponent, SlCatalogComponent]
})
export class SlEcommModule { }
```

The component im trying to use is SlCatalogComponent. The other component, SlEcommComponent, seems to work but this is the component that was auto generated by the angular CLI.

So heres a snippet of the consuming projects appmodule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CommonDataService } from './_services/common-data.service';
import { SignInComponent } from './sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { SlEcommModule } from 'sl-test';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignInComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    SlEcommModule
  ],
  providers: [CommonDataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally on the signin components template, im using a component from the library i made like this:

```
<sl-catalog></sl-catalog>
```

Im not sure what else im missing since the default component in the library works, and mine does not.

--Edit--

So ive narrowed down the problem to my npm package not having the a certain folder included when its being published.

After adding the `"files": ["lib"]` to the package.json everything seems to be working ok except the intellisense here is screwed up:

[image]

Comment: can you share your main.ts

Comment: any other erros there, and did you install your library in your project? and you should import browsermodule in your imports array.

Comment: Did you import `NgModule` decorator in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @StasAmasev Yes i did, i know it looks like i didnt but i doctored up that snippet cause there was allot of stuff in there and i didnt wanna blow out this question

Comment: @AakashGarg yes i did also import the browsermodule, i removed some stuff from these snippets, the angular app im consuming the library in is a fully function angular app, however whenn adding <sl-catalog> to the template i get compile errors

Comment: You are importing `AppModule` into `AppModule`

Comment: @callOfCode that was another pasting issue whoops. Im not actually importing appmodule in my project lol

Comment: @SanzioSan what are those compile errors?

Comment: @AakashGarg so ive narrowed down the error. It seems like when i install my npm package, theres a folder missing. The dist folder has the folder thats missing. But when i do an npm install on my package its missing the /lib folder

Comment: @SanzioSan please post the screenshot of complete error above.

Comment: @AakashGarg I posted a screenshot of this new error i am recieving. I got the component to show up properly but the intellisense is screwed up. I think it may have something to do with how im packing the file... or something

Comment: @SanzioSan you have to upload only your library on npmjs, not the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to fix my issue is adding `"files": ["./src/lib"]` to my package.json